# "Open" button not showing up for Flutterflow app on Google play store (closed/internal test)

Tags: android, flutter, flutterflow

I know Flutterflow has a one-clic deployment feature, but I would like to learn doing it myself. I managed to get it into the Google play store for a closed test. I could download and install it on the phone, but after that I could only see the "uninstall" button, not the "open" button. Also the app icon did not appear anywhere on the phone. I could find it in the list of settings>applications, but there is not much I can do from there. I noticed that in that list, the app did not have the proper icon (only an android robot) and no authorization (internet or file) was granted to it...which seems weird.

Here is how I deployed my Flutterflow app the Google play store in closed test mode:  I downloaded the APK from Flutterflow. Then I opened it in Android Studio, and built a signed AAB from there. I did all the preliminary setup in the Google play console, and created a closed test release using the AAB file. After 4 days waiting for Google to review it, I received the link to be shared with my testers....
by the way if someone here volunteers to test it, please let me know.
Then I downloaded the app to my phone, in order to run a first test.
I also did the same in the "internal testing" but same result.
Any help is welcome

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.